# get_value() method is not returning value of the node,the type of the node is ExtensionObject

Tags: python, opc-ua, getvalue

On using below code i am not able to get the value of particular node.

```
from opcua import Client, ua
server_url = "opc.tcp://localhost:4840"
client = Client(server_url)
client.connect()
try:
    node_id = "ns=1;s=data/OpcUaServer/channels/1/0_VALUES"
    node = client.get_node(node_id)
    data_value = node.get_data_value()
    print("Node Value:", data_value)
    print("Node Value:", data_value)
finally:
    client.disconnect()
```

Output received:
`Node Value: ExtensionObject(TypeId:FourByteNodeId(ns=1;i=1), Encoding:1, 5 bytes)`
`<class 'opcua.ua.uatypes.ExtensionObject'>`
So my Client need to know the Extension Object. The Problem is I can't load the type definitions. After connecting and running `client.load_type_defitnitions()`,there is nothing to happen,the outout also recieved: `Node Value: ExtensionObject(TypeId:FourByteNodeId(ns=1;i=1), Encoding:1, 5 bytes)`.I have searched many methods, but they have no effect. If anyone can help, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

load `load_type_defitnitions` works only for legacy servers. Some server doens't expose this infomartion anymore.

As the opcua library is not supported anymore, try switch to asyncua and use the syncclient.

There you can try `load_data_type_definitions` instead of `load_type_defitnitions`. If this doesn't work try to open a pr in github of asyncua and we try to help you there.

Comment: I have read the ExtensionObject by the code:```data_value.Body```,but the print is ```b'\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff'```,that's why?I want to get the bytestring like 844d000000e5a00bc...@Schroeder

Comment: Switch to asyncua… There is no support for python opcua anymore, so if you have a error nobody can help you…